# go build is not working because git getting fatal read error connection reset by peer on Linux

Tags: git, go, ubuntu, gitlab

I am getting a weird error on Ubuntu attempting to compile an internal tool at work, with go. I've changed names for company sensitivity

```
$ go build -o internal-tool .
go: gitlab.com/<company>/platform/<tool-sdk>@v0.0.0-<version-number>: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /home/<myhomefolder>/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/<unique-hash>: exit status 128:
    fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

I have my SSH keys to gitlab added for every computer I have tried this on, I am able to git clone this tool-sdk manually, and it clones just fine.

If I ran `go build -o internal-tool .` on Windows, it's very telling. When it tries to git fetch this project it displays the attached UI dialog box

[image: GitLab login screen]

I have 2FA setup so password doesn't work, and for some reason, Browser never worked, it never loaded the browser window with the gitlab login. Access token did work however, so I was able to do this on Windows.

It looks like my go or the git that my go is using on Linux, does not have the ability to load this dialog box or it does not have an analog for this in order to login to Gitlab. I have coworkers who have not run into this issue. Also if it's any use, I have seen this both on the go installed via apt on Ubuntu and on the go install using snap on Ubuntu (on two different machines). When I open this project in VSCode, it also relays the above error, so no surprise there.

Any suggestions on what to do here? Is there some git or gitlab setup that I have to do specific to go? Or a different go needs to be installed?

Comment: See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72095544/1256452), but also note that [this issue has been open for years now](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26232).

Answer (score 2):

A prompt asking for a password or token means one of the dependencies of your project requires Go to clone it using an HTTPS URL (not an SSH one)

The dialog box itself comes from the [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) which includes in its [v2.0.692](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.692) with the support for GitLab repositories, [adding GUI prompts for GitLab authentication](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/pull/621).

Not that you can make sure you don't see any popup with `export GCM_INTERACTIVE=false` in the shell where you do a `go build`, ensuring the build fails with an error message instead of a popup.

In your case, try:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@gitlab.com/.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
```

That will try and use SSH URL instead.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Also installing GCM works manually on WIndows in cases where you have a funky git setup. Tried it on another computer and just installing GCM worked there as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `GOPATH` has an issue. Check that your path variable also includes the `<GOPATH>/bin` just type `echo $PATH`.

You can add it to your shell temporary

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

to add it to your shell permanently edit `~/.zshr` or `~/.bashrc` then source the shell

```
$SHELL
```

More info about the [GOPATH](https://go.dev/doc/gopath_code#GOPATH)